# Salesforce language detection

Tags: apex, api, language

I want to know Saleforce got any api for detect a sentence or a word language. I just want to know the the language but not the translation.

Comment: goto to settings->advanced user details->locale
sf will translate fields based on this selection

Comment: Hi Ilya, my case is I need to create a social post in apex, and route to proper agent who spoke in different language based on the social post content. So, I need to know what is the language of social post content first. you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce got no any native API for recognize a sentence language. But I just found Social Post object got a "Language" field which can recognize a sentence language from social media and push to Salesforce as a Social Post record

Answer (score 3):

Apex provides this method to detect and return the current user's language.

```
 UserInfo.getLanguage());
```

[This](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm) is a full list of languages supported in Salesforce. If you want to auto-detect the language of any word, you can use any 3rd party language detection API as well.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I know Salesforce got translation API, is it possible I adopt these APIs to achieve my goal? My goal is auto-detect the language of any specific word.

Comment: Yes, what exactly do you want to detect and translate within Salesforce?

Comment: I need to create a social post by adopted apex, these social posts maybe include difference type of language like, en, zh, it and so forth. Then how I know what is the language of the social post before I assign this social post to en, zh or it queue.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, You got any idea

Comment: You can just as well use any language translation API for that, why do you need this to be done specifically using Apex API?

Comment: because if Salesforce got native language detection API, I can directly apdoted and no need concern too much about compatible and security compare with 3th party APIs. May I ask, How I can get the document or reference of language detection API of Salesforce?